# Float Bug on Square Root Function Python

Tags: python

I have the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math
i = 2
isprime = True
n = input("Enter a number: ")
while i <= math.sqrt(n):
    i += 1
    if n % i == 0:
        isprime = False
    if isprime == False:
        print("Not Prime")
    else:
        print("It's Prime!")
```

And everything works besides the square root part. getting error: TypeError: a float is required. I changed while i <= to while float(i) <=, but that did not fix the error! What do I do?

Comment: where are you getting the TypeError?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I tried:>>> math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951

Comment: You should not accuse your language runtime of having a bug, unless you are very sure the bug is 1) not in *your* code, 2) not in your environment, and 3) actually in the language. Please change the title to something like "TypeError when doing math.sqrt(input("type a number"))" or something. Also please consider removing sections of unnecessary code in future submissions. Thank you.

Comment: This will work in Python 2.7 since the string gets evaled. But it will not work in Python 3 since input no longer gets evaled in that version.

Answer (score 2):

`input(...)` returns a string. You are trying to take the `sqrt("of a string")`. Use `int(input("Enter a number: "))` instead.

Even though you claim to be using python2 with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, make sure that `python` is actually python2. You can check this by just typing:

```
/usr/bin/env python
```

In a terminal and looking at the version number, e.g.:

```
% /usr/bin/env python                                                                                                
Python 2.7.2 (default, ...
...
```

If it is set to Python 3.x, this is a problem with your system administrator. This **should not be done** and should immediately be changed. Python3 programs must be invoked with `python3`; this "tweak" will break any python2 programs on the current Linux system.

---

Apparently `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))` so would work in python2, but wouldn't in python3.:

```
% python2                                                                                                            
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 19 2011, 20:41:43) [GCC] on linux2                                                        
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(input())
5
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Versus:

```
% python3                                                                                                            
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 18 2011, 16:24:40) [GCC] on linux2                                                        
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(input())
5
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: Not true. `raw_input` returns a string, but `input` will return an `int` or a `float` if that what you input. From the docs, `input` is: Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

Comment: >>> a = input()      gives  3.5
>>> type(a)          gives  <type 'float'>

Comment: Amusing, apparently `input` is a thing in python2.7 but not in python3. Since this is clearly python2, deleting answer. **edit: Actually since this code works just fine in python2, I think somehow the person is using python3.**

Comment: Yes, this answer is actually correct for python 3. And using python 3 is the only way the op would get the mentioned exception.

Comment: @stranac: Exactly, which is why I am not deleting it.

Comment: The use of python3 is further supported by the fact that it looks as if `print` is being used as a function is the example code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `Python3`. In python3 [input returns string](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#input).

```
>>> x = input()
2
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> math.sqrt(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

Type-cast `string` to `float` and it should work just fine.

```
>>> math.sqrt(float(x))
1.4142135623730951
>>>
```

Comment: No, you're absolutely correct. Just adding some additional reference material, although I just noticed I duplicated your link. Edited my comment already.

Comment: Necessary warning about `eval`: don't use it unless you're sure that's what you want; it allows the user to run arbitrary code in cases like this.  In this case, `int` is preferable.